# DigitalOcean integrating a React app inside Django

Tags: reactjs, django, webpack, babeljs

I'm using Django 4 and wish to integrate a ReactJS application within the Django framework.

I chose to use the exact approach [here](https://dev.to/zachtylr21/how-to-serve-a-react-single-page-app-with-django-1a1l) to start and installed it identically as outlined.

Here's a list of the installed components and versions:

```
├── @babel/core@7.20.12
├── @babel/preset-env@7.20.2
├── @babel/preset-react@7.18.6
├── babel-loader@9.1.2
├── clean-webpack-plugin@4.0.0
├── css-loader@6.7.3
├── react-dom@18.2.0
├── react@18.2.0
├── style-loader@3.3.1
├── webpack-bundle-tracker@0.4.3
├── webpack-cli@5.0.1
└── webpack@5.75.0
```

I do not want to post all of my code here since it is 100% identical to the code in the link above.

Unfortunately, I'm receiving a strange error in the console:

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:8001/frontend/static/frontend/frontend-dc3188e75be82e0a01e0.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

127.0.0.1/:1 Refused to execute script from 'http://127.0.0.1:8001/frontend/static/frontend/frontend-dc3188e75be82e0a01e0.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
```

This appears to be related to the path, but the referenced JS filename is spelled correctly and exists at the exact referenced path.

The server console also displays a similar error:

```
Not Found: /frontend/static/frontend/frontend-dc3188e75be82e0a01e0.js
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the feedback.  This is how I ultimately performed this integration entirely using a combination of online tutorials, the feedback here and the github repo for django-webpack-loader.

Please see the comment at the very bottom for details on resolving the path issue with DigitalOcean Spaces.

Keep in mind this approach below eliminates a lot of the unnecessary steps and ensures the latest versions of the software are used.  References are below.

If React and React-Dom are not already installed into your environment, start here:

```
npm install react react-dom
```

**A: Setup the Django App and Dependencies**

1. Create the frontend app in Django

```
python manage.py startapp frontend
```

2. Update the list of installed apps within settings.py or base.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
  'frontend',
  ...
]
```

3. Create the templates folder for the frontend app. In my case, my Templates directory is in the root of the project, so under the folder I added 'frontend': ./templates/frontend
4. Create the template in the newly created frontend folder: ./templates/frontend/index.html
5. Add the following into the index.html, which contains Django tags to use later for rendering the bundle:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load render_bundle from webpack_loader %}
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>My Site</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app"></div>
  <p>hello</p>
  {% render_bundle 'frontend' %}
</body>
</html>
```

6. Create the view in the app frontend/views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def index(request):
  return render(request, 'frontend/index.html')
```

7. Update the URL pattern within urls.py at the project level: config/urls.py.  In this case, the react app is loading from the root of the domain.  I recommend using this configuration (outlined in step 7 and 8) or you will receive path errors.  This can be changed later.

```
path('', include('frontend.urls'))
```

8. Update the URL patterns within urls.py at the app level:

```
path('', views.index)
```

9. At this point, you can test and run the server or continue on.  **If you test, remember that you have 2 Django tags loading in Step 5 that you will need to comment out.**

```
python manage.py runserver
```

B: Install React & Babel

1. From the root of the project, run the following command to create the package.json file.

```
npm init -y
```

2. Setup Babel.

```
npm install --save-dev @babel/core
```

3. Install Babel plugins:

```
npm install --save-dev @babel/preset-env @babel/preset-react
```

4. Create a .babelrc file in the root of your project and add this into it:

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"]
}
```

C: Install & Configure Webpack

1. Install Webpack and the additional packages.

```
npm install --save-dev webpack webpack-cli webpack-bundle-tracker babel-loader css-loader style-loader clean-webpack-plugin
```

2. Create a webpack.config.js file in the root of the project.

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const BundleTracker = require('webpack-bundle-tracker');
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin')

module.exports = {
    context: __dirname,
    entry: {
        frontend: './frontend/src/index.js',

    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve('./frontend/static/frontend/'),
        filename: '[name]-[hash].js',
        publicPath: 'static/frontend/',
    },
    plugins: [
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
        new BundleTracker({ filename: './webpack-stats.json' })
    ],
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: ['babel-loader'],
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
            },
        ],
    },
}
```

3. Add the following scripts to your package.json file located in the project root.  You should already have scripts in this file; just add the two new lines of code for "dev" and "build".:

```
{
  ...,
  "scripts": {
    ...,
    "dev": "webpack --config webpack.config.js --watch --mode development",
    "build": "webpack --config webpack.config.js --mode production"
  }
}
```

C: Create a basic React APP for testing

1. In the frontend app folder, create a folder called src.
2. In the src folder, create an App.js file. Be sure to follow the capitalization.  And, add the following to it:

```
import React from 'react'

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>Hello, World!</div>
  )
}

export default App
```

2. In the src folder, create an index.js file and add the following to it:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import App from './App'

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('app')
)
```

D: Install Webpack Loader & Configure

1. Run the following command:

```
pip install django-webpack-loader
```

2. Update the list of installed apps within settings.py or base.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
  ...
  'webpack_loader',
  ...
)
```

3. Also, update the Webpack Loader configurations in the settings.py or base.py file:

```
WEBPACK_LOADER = {
  'DEFAULT': {
    'CACHE': not DEBUG,
    'STATS_FILE': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'webpack-stats.json'),
    'POLL_INTERVAL': 0.1,
    'IGNORE': [r'.+\.hot-update.js', r'.+\.map'],
  }
}
```

If you receive an error related to DEBUG, check the available options in the django-webpack-loader instructions (see below for link).

E: Compile the frontend asset files and test

1. If you commented out the django tags in step A9, remove the comment before proceeding.
2. Run the following command:

```
npx webpack --config webpack.config.js --watch
```

3. Run your server:

```
python manage.py runserver
```

4. Open your browser and navigate to the root of your site.  You should receive a Hello World printout on the screen.  If not, and you only receive an empty white screen, the react assets are not loading.  Check the server console and/or the browser console for errors.

References:
**Outdated Tutorial**
https://dev.to/zachtylr21/how-to-serve-a-react-single-page-app-with-django-1a1l

**django-webpack-loader repo**
https://github.com/django-webpack/django-webpack-loader

Comment: Additionally, paths become more complicated when integrating with Digitalocean and using Spaces (AWS Buckets).  You'll need to manually update the webpack.config file's publicPath to reflect the URL for Spaces.  I.E. publicPath: 'https://sfo.digitaloceanspaces.com/my-space/static/frontend/'

Answer (score 0):

the link you provided is an old tutorial. You should always follow the [documentation](https://github.com/django-webpack/django-webpack-loader). Based on docs

> You must generate the front-end bundle using webpack-bundle-tracker
> before using django-webpack-loader. You can compile the assets and
> generate the bundles by running:
>
> ```
> npx webpack --config webpack.config.js --watch
> ```

this is webpack config setting related to `webpack-bundle-tracker`. It spits out the `webpack-stats.json` file and looks like django `webpack-loader` reads from this .json file

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const BundleTracker = require('webpack-bundle-tracker');

module.exports = {
  context: __dirname,
  entry: './assets/js/index',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve('./assets/webpack_bundles/'),
    filename: "[name]-[hash].js"
  },
  plugins: [
    new BundleTracker({filename: './webpack-stats.json'})
  ],
}
```

and then:

```
WEBPACK_LOADER = {
  'DEFAULT': {
    'CACHE': not DEBUG,
    'STATS_FILE': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'webpack-stats.json'),
    'POLL_INTERVAL': 0.1,
    'IGNORE': [r'.+\.hot-update.js', r'.+\.map'],
  }
```

Comment: Thank you.  I did reference the documentation but I didn’t account for the order of execution.  I’ll test this approach and respond.  Thank you for your response.

Comment: important thing i smake sure this `webpack-stats.json` should be inside the basedir.